# Trim не правильно убирает пробелы в начале строчки

Tags: java, android

Не правильно работает `String.trim`, вернее не так как мне хотелось.

Например строчка: `!   привет как     дела   !`  //форум затирает пробелы, написал восклицательные знаки.

Он сделает из нее: `привет как дела`, а мне не требуется убирать пробелы между словами, а всеголишь убирать лишние пробелы в начале и конце строчки, как можно это исправить?

Comment: 10 лет метод `trim` работал так, как написно в документации и вот теперь такой поворот, Дениса Котлярова не устратвает, как он работает и его нужно исправить. Чтож - напишите свой, правильный метод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возникает у меня подозрение, что пробелы сжимаются при выводе по той же схеме, что в html, а trim тут не при чём:

```css
span {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<span>   привет как     дела   </span><br>
<span style=white-space:pre>   привет как     дела   </span><br>
<span style=white-space:normal>   привет как     дела   </span><br>
```

Comment: Единственный человек который подсказал, экстрасенс) все работает.. буду знать...

Answer (score 4):

Ничего `trim()` не затирает кроме крайних пробелов

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "   привет как     дела   ";
        System.out.println(s.trim()); // Выводит "привет как     дела" без кавычек
    }
}
```

Comment: Сам код проверял?

Comment: и я знаю кто это мне пишет)

Comment: @ДенисКотляров конечно проверял, к чему вопрос?

Comment: @ДенисКотляровб http://ideone.com/UatdUE